# C# EFCORE using two primary keys (compound key) in SQLITE

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

The appointment table has two primary keys - MeetingId and CaseId. Each one is unique in the Cases Table and Meetings table.
An appointment is defined as a case set on a specific meeting. This combination is unique, as there can be two rows with same values.
I am trying to set the dbcontext using a table with these two primary keys.
I have read that in EF core you set the primary keys by overriding the method `OnModelCreating`. I have done so but I receive the following error: `System.InvalidOperationException: The data is NULL at ordinal 3. This method can't be called on NULL values. Check using IsDBNull before calling.`
I have checked and all the rows have values.

**The table structure for Apppontments in SQLITE**

```
CREATE TABLE Appointments (
    MeetingId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CaseId   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Observation    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        MeetingId,
        CaseId
    ),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        CaseId
    )
    REFERENCES Cases (CaseId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        MeetingId
    )
    REFERENCES Meetings (MeetingId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**The DB context in c#**

```
 public class CaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Case> Cases { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Appointment>().HasKey(t => new {
                t.MeetingId,
                t.CaseId,
            });

        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string connstr = @"Data Source=personalcases.db";
            optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connstr);
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
```

**Update:**
I have this constructor in my class for initializing the context:
`private readonly CaseContext _context = new CaseContext();`

Also, the `Case` class:

```
  public class Case
    {
        public int CaseId { get; set; }
        public string CaseName  { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Appointment>
            Appointments
        { get; set; } =
            new ObservableCollection<Appointment>();
        
    }
```

At the constructor method of the viewmodel class I am using this method to bind the Cases info to my WPF app:

`CasesList = new BindableCollection<Case>(_context.Cases.Where(d => d.CaseName == "testcase");`

The error occurs when I select an item from the `CasesList`

> System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Appointments' value (type 'ICollection`1') from 'SelectedCase' (type 'CaseProxy'). BindingExpression:Path=SelectedCase.Appointments; DataItem='ListaSedintaViewModel' (HashCode=40262542); target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Property accessor 'Appointments' on object 'Castle.Proxies.CaseProxy' threw the following exception:'The data is NULL at ordinal 3. This method can't be called on NULL values. Check using IsDBNull before calling.' ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The data is NULL at ordinal 3. This method can't be called on NULL values. Check using IsDBNull before calling.
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteValueReader.GetInt64(Int32 ordinal)
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteValueReader.GetInt32(Int32 ordinal)
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 ordinal)
> at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Load[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.EntityFinde`1.Load(INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry entry)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.NavigationEntry.Load()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.CollectionEntry.Load()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyLoader.Load(Object entity, String navigationName)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies.Internal.LazyLoadingInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
> at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
> at Castle.Proxies.CaseProxy.get_Appointments()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Object component)
> at MS.Internal.Data.ValueTable.GetValue(Object item, PropertyDescriptor pd, Boolean indexerIsNext)
> at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(Object item, Int32 level)
> at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Int32 k)'

Comment: Where do you get that error? What is the *actual* full exception text? This message complains about the data, not the primary key definition. Somehow, in code that's not included in the question, an attempt was made to load NULLs and cast it into a value type

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have updated the question providing the details. I thought it is stricly a matter of using a compound key because I have just modified the table. Before, it had a single primary key and the same code worked without raising any error.

Comment: You still didn't post the full exception. The part you posted complains about trying to bind to a null `Appointments` property. Did you try creating a master-detail form and tried to display appointments for a Case that has no appointments?

Comment: I have posted the full exception now. Yes, it is a master-detail and for the selected case there are two appointments. The populated that is the same as before setting compound keys. This is why I thought that it has something to do with setting two primary keys.

Comment: Also, I have translated the class and property names strictly for posting the questions and there may be some inconsistencies in the code.

Comment: The exception complains that one of the properties of the lazily loaded appointments is null when it shouldn't be. Change your code to store the query results to a variable and debug your application to see what's actually loaded. Consider using eager loading during debugging (ie use `Include()`) to see what's loaded for all cases.

Comment: I have loaded the query in a variable and found out that in the appointments table there was an entry in the MeetingId that didn't have a coresponding value in the Meetings table. This caused the error.  You were right and I have jumped out to the conclusion. Thank you. I think I will delete the question as there isn't any issue regarding the question.